# Wordpress - current-menu-item class missing

Tags: wordpress, menu

In a custom template file I'm inserting one of my custom menus:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Internal' ));?>
```

However the menu fails to generate the class current-menu-item for the current li item.

I am inserting a menu in the same way for menus in other pages without any issues.

What might cause Wordpress to fail output of the current-menu-item?

Cheers
Teodor

Answer (score 3):

Try to use  wp_reset_query() function.

```
            <?php 
                 wp_reset_query();

                 wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Internal' ));
             ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the menu  function

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'primary','menu' => 'Internal' ));?>
```

you will get  the   .current-menu-item in the li and you can make the effect accordingly